# Weird behaviour on ICS whole day events on iPhone Calendar

Tags: iphone, calendar, icalendar

our sports website provides an ICS calendar for our matches, draws etc.

For retrieving the ICS file we use a PHP script which reads the local ics file and then does some optional filtering on the VEVENT records etc. and returns the ICS data.

I have subscribed this ICS webcal via `webcal://....` on my iPhone.

I now have the weird behaviour that SOME whole day events (DURATION:P1D) like this

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTSTART;VALUE=DATE:20120623
DURATION:P1D
TRANSP:TRANSPARENT
SUMMARY:Auslosung: VWM: Super Globe
DESCRIPTION:VWM: Super Globe
UID:20110124@thw-provinzial.de
CATEGORIES:THW-Termin
URL:http://www.thw-provinzial.de/thw/
COMMENT:TYPE=VWM
END:VEVENT
```

span two days in my iPhone Calendar if I subscribe the PHP script via `webcal://www.thw-provinzial.de/thw/ics.php?config=all?`.
(It is shown on 20120623 and 20120624)

If I subscribe the ics file directly via `http://www.thw-provinzial.de/thw/thwdate2.ics` the event is shown correctly only on day 20120623.

If I do a

```
wget http://www.thw-provinzial.de/thw/thwdate2.ics
wget http://www.thw-provinzial.de/thw/ics.php?config=all
```

and then diff the two outputs the only difference is the `X-WR-CALNAME` all other content is identical.

Could it be that some header information in the response is confusing the iPhone?

Response header of the thwdate2.ics -here the behvaiour is fine

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: XXXXXX
Server: Apache
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Jun 2012 20:05:04 GMT
ETag: "6c6f78d-c54d-4c260194d7c00"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 50509
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/calendar
Age: 787
```

Response header of the ics.php - here we have the problem with spanning over 2 days

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Thu, XXXXXX
Server: Apache
Content-Disposition: inline; filename=thwdates.ics
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Last-Modified: Wed, 13 Jun 2012 20:05:04 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I tried the two links, but your example event is no longer in them. Perhaps you resolved your query ?

Comment: I just checked the ICS files, but the event "Auslosung: VWM: Super Globe
" is still there...